# Grafana image renderer plugin not able to install - signature has been modified

Tags: ubuntu, grafana

I am trying to install grafana image renderer plugin on Ubuntu 20.04 with Grafana 7.5.9, but it fails due to certificate problems:

```
user@leo:~$ sudo grafana-cli plugins install grafana-image-renderer
installing grafana-image-renderer @ 3.2.1
from: https://grafana.com/api/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/versions/3.2.1/download
into: /var/lib/grafana/plugins


✔ Installed grafana-image-renderer successfully 

Restart grafana after installing plugins . <service grafana-server restart>

user@leo:~$ sudo service grafana-server restart
user@leo:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/grafana/grafana.log
t=2021-10-24T00:48:04+0200 lvl=warn msg="Some plugins failed to load" logger=plugins errors="[plugin \"grafana-image-renderer\"'s signature has been modified]"
```

While querying the plugin I do get:

```
curl ... 'https://user:pw@mydomain.com/app/render/d/coziavM7z/db-name-... '
```

[image]

I added this to grafana.ini and restarted grafana:

```
[plugins]
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = grafana-image-renderer
```

The issue has also been documented here:
https://issueexplorer.com/issue/grafana/grafana-image-renderer/225

In my case there is not file called MANIFEST.TXT

The plugin section shows this:

[image]

I am running out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Maybe try it with a newer Grafana. Although it says [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/) "Dependencies: Grafana >= 7.0.0", it is possible that a newer one might be actually required. With Grafana 8.2.1, I'm at least not getting a "signature has been modified" when I repeat your steps.

Comment: Tried with Grafana v7.5.4, still getting the same error as I got with Grafana v8.2.1: "Failed to get browser version" right after "Registering plugin" id=grafana-image-renderer. I have a dockerized setup but I didn't follow the docker-specific instructions from the plugin's setup doc..

Comment: From the documentation it is not clear to me if there is anything else needed to be installed despite of the plugin. I am querying the URL from remote.

Comment: @V-R added more information to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I finaly found a solution for this problem, although I did run into another one (timeout) the plugin seems to be installed.

Remove manifest:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/grafana/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/MANIFEST.txt  /var/lib/grafana/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/MANIFEST.txt.bak
```

Allow unsigned plugin:

```
[plugins]
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = grafana-image-renderer
```

Install chrome on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo /etc/init.d/grafana-server restart
```